# Being redirected one page back

Tags: php, html, sql

My goal is that the user will be redirected to the page that he initially was when he pressed the login button and has inputed his username and password. So far I had no problem doing so. However, if I press the view more button so that I am redirected to the singleproduct.php and then press the back from the browser going back to search.php and after that try to login I am redirected to the singleproduct.php instead of search.php. I had no problem doing this on other pages including the singleproduct.php or any other of my pages and even in the search.php if I dont end up there by going back or forward through the browser buttons it still works.

Does it have to do with the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] not being given the new url or have I messed up somewhere else?

I was wondering why this is happening and what can I do to fix it.

search.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
$_SESSION['current_page'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="sea" action="search.php" method="GET">
        <input class="searchbar" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        <button class="searchbutton" name="submit-search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
    //button for login
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['submit-search'])) {
        $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['search']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%' OR product_category LIKE '$search'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($queryResult > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            //read from database
            <a href="singleproduct.php?viewmore=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"class="viewmore btn-info" role="button">View More</a>
            <?php }
        } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

singleproduct.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
$_SESSION['current_page'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="sea" action="search.php" method="GET">
        <input class="searchbar" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        <button class="searchbutton" name="submit-search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
    //button for login
    <?php
    $id = $_GET[viewmore];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE product_id='".$id."' ");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 //read the database for the single item
 }?>
</body>
</html>
```

includes/login.inc.php

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //Error Handlers
    if(){
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
            $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
            $_SESSION['u_status'] = $row['user_status'];
            $_SESSION['u_level'] = $row['user_level'];
            $_SESSION['success-message'] = '';
            header("Location: ". $_SESSION['current_page']);
            exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you press the Back button in your browser, your browser does exactly that. It goes back. It doesn't actually refresh the page. So your PHP isn't fired again and doesn't update the session variable.

Comment: You just need to get the page they came from whenever they hit the login page, set it in a session, after they have logged in successfully, if session has a valid page, set it to a var, unset the session, and redirect them using the var. On the login page, simply check if they're already logged in and if so show message "already logged in". There's not much you can do about certain aspects of people pressing links and forms then back having POST data stored in their browser history.

Comment: @James Thank you! I will go get it done.